# linux equivalent of dir /b /s /a:-D (print full path of all files recursively)

Tags: linux, shell, find, ls

i just today migrated to linux and i would like to know how to do this with ls command (ar what you thing is best). The idea is to obtain all files with full path in a directory, including subdirectories...
The cmd command i was using is:

```
dir /b /s /a:-D
```

Comment: Is the output of `find` what you're looking for?

Comment: ... or `find . -not -type d` (to correspond to the `/a:-D`) maybe?

Comment: almost!, it gives me relative paths, i want full paths, at least back to home

Comment: so `find "$PWD" -not -type d` should do that I think

Comment: The propesed command gives this error message on UNIX: `find: bad option -not`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I can tell, your `dir` command descends into subdirectories (`/S`), skipping headers and summaries (`/B`) and omitting files whose **d**irectory **a**ttribute is set (`/A:-D`)

The portable way to do that in Linux would be via the `find` command - it descends into subdirectories by default, and can be made to omit directories by adding `-not -type d` (`!` may be used as a synonym for `-not`)

By default, it reports paths relative to the starting point, so to get absolute paths you can use the shell's present working directory variable `PWD`:

```
find "$PWD" -not -type d
```

If you are using a shell that supports recursive pattern matches (aka "globstar") and glob qualifiers, there are other options - in `zsh` for example you could do

```
ls -1d **/*(^D:A)
```

or simply

```
printf '%s\n' **/*(^D:A)
```

You may also want to consider whether you really want "not directories" or "plain files":

```
find "$PWD" -type f
```

or (zsh)

```
printf '%s\n' **/*(.:A)
```

Comment: You did never test your `find` command on UNIX, since this results in: `find: bad option -not`

Comment: @schily the question only asks about Linux, and the answer only claims to address Linux.

Comment: There is still no reason to give a nonportable answer and to mention a nonhelpful alias instead of the official method.

Comment: @schily if you have a portable solution, why don't just post an answer yourself?

Comment: there are downvoting trolls that downvote all answers that inform about vendor lock ins caused by GNU tools.